# Watson Assistant Wordpress Chat Plugin Not Focusing on / Scrolling to Newest Message

Tags: wordpress, watson, watson-conversation

We have been developing a chatbot using IBM's Watson Assistant work spaces and conversation plugin for wordpress. Although we have nearly completed the actual chatbot, we have noticed an issue with the "customer" interface on our [test page](https://www.forsythcountyclerk.com/tabitha-test/). For whatever reason, the chat window does not automatically focus on the newest messages. In other words, once the messages fill up the chat window, the user must scroll to keep up with the conversation, which is an obvious inconvenience for anyone wanting to chat. Any advice or suggestions would be welcome because.

I have tried several things to correct the issue, including clearing the site cache, but nothing has helped.

I also already posted on the WordPress support thread on 6/14/2018 (along with two follow up messages) have received absolutely no response from Cognitive Class. I'm just posting here to see if anyone can offer possible solutions.

Comment: This isn't an issue with Watson Assistant, it's the plugin. You should create a post on their support forum asking  @cognitiveclass  for assistance. Detail OS/browser, steps and expected behaviour. Also create a video rather than a link to a webpage that may no longer exist.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty I appreciate your suggestions, but I posted on the Wordpress Support Forum for the plugin before coming here. I posted it on 6/14/2018 and have gotten absolutely no response from IBM Cognitive class, despite two follow up messages --it's now 6/21/2018.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty As for the video suggestion, I think it's a great idea, but I don't have the resources available. There's a complicated situation in my gov't agency that prevents using software to record a video.I refuse to use my personal equipment to do so because my property could be seized under the right circumstances due to "work use".

(sorry about the two comments, I accidentally pressed enter and then took too long to edit my first comment...)